# Using Apple script to remove app by given bundle name of bundle identifier

Tags: applescript

I can know the app bundle name or bundle identifier by Info.plist.
But the bundle display name had been localization which means it would display different app name in each locale.

Could I use apple script to remove this app by using the specific bundle name or bundle identifier?

I have tried

```
tell applications "Finder"
  delete file "APP BUNDLE NAME" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
end tell
```

The results said it can not find the "APP BUNDEL NAME"
Since bundle name is "AAA", but display name is "BBB" in locale 1, "CCC" in locale 2

Is there any approach to write an universal script to remove app for all locale?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Finder` the specifier to get the file reference by bundle identifier is `application file id`

```
tell application "Finder"
    delete application file id "com.foo.bar"
end tell
```